# How do I add GRUB_COMMAND_LINE argument to non-default boot entry?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.4.4 server and Fedora 27. Ubuntu is the default boot entry. I have to boot with the 'noapic' command (because of the older motherboard I guess) and I edited `/etc/default/grub` to include `GRUB_COMMAND_LINE="noapic"` and/or `GRUB_COMMAND_LINE_DEFAULT="noapic"` (I can't tell what the different is - thought maybe default only applied to the default boot entry)

But with either or both entries set with "noapic" only the default Ubuntu boot process loads with `noapic` and completes.

How do I set up the command to apply to my Fedora 27 boot entry, either specifically or because it applies to all boot entries?

Comment: Are you editing the file directly or using a tool?

Comment: I'm editing /etc/default/grub directly and then running update-grub. Although you did not imply it, just to be clear, I am NOT editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my laptop, I added `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.` to my default boot entry, I added the same setting right into the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` after running `update-grub` for other entries